# 500 error when connecting to parse.com via php SDK

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am trying to connect to a parse app using the php SDK.

```
<?php
    $app_id = '';
    $rest_key = '';
    $master_key = '';
    use Parse\ParseClient;
    ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );

    use Parse\ParseObject;

    $testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
    $testObject->set("foo", "bar");
    $testObject->save();
?>
```

**UPDATED:**

The error is:

Fatal error: Class 'Parse\ParseClient' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs...

Comment: You should check the error log or enable error display to see what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by adding:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```